# Prove that ECB-mode of a block cipher is not EAV-secure

Tags: block-cipher, ecb

I know that ECB-mode of block cipher is not recommended to use as it is not secure and is not even EAV-secure. However, I still don't get how to prove that it is not EAV-secure and what adversary is associated with this insecurity? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Edited: I found a similar article here: [Proving a scheme's EAV-insecurity](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67932/proving-a-schemes-eav-insecurity),
and also figured it out. Thank you for all your helps.

Comment: Perhaps a partial duplicate:  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67932/   and
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83910/

Comment: Note that EAV secure is indistinguishable encryption against an eavesdropper. It is defined in Katz & Lindells "Introduction to Cryptography", 2nd edition, page 30/31.

Comment: Hint, what's the problem with ECB? What happens if both of the messages consist of not one but two blocks? Could you define a pair of messages in such a way that you can show which one was encrypted?

Comment: I also see a possible problem with your question, the security is against *any* adversary $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. you get to play the adversary and define the messages $m_1$ and $m_2$. Although I might be wrong and you are already getting that.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I figured it out.